# template_name not resolving for some views

Tags: django, django-views

My webapp was working fine, but after doing some ldap configurations (only changes regarding ldap in settings.py) my routing to certain pages seemed to brake.  My urls.py seems to be in order but when i go to the view page i want to see it gives me another template.html file.

my urls.py

```
appname = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', views.LogOutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('index/search', views.SearchView.as_view(), name="search"),
    path('index/<slug:key>', views.EpicView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    **path('index/exec_report', views.ExecView.as_view(), name = "exec"),
    **path('index/exec_version_report', views.ExecVersionView.as_view(), name = "version"),
    path('index/', views.IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

Now all the paths work well, but the 2 with `**` next to them are the ones returning with the EpicView template

So in my index.html is where you click on a search to bring you to `index/exec_version_report`

index.html

```
<form method="GET" action = "{% url 'app:version' %}">

 <select name ="versionA" >
     <option value = 0>0</option>
 </select>

 <select name = "versionB">
     <option value = 4.2> 4.2</option>
     <option value = 4> 4.0</option>
 </select>
  <input  type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

Now the url routing is correct when i click on "Search" but it is giving me the wrong template, but you can see that the template_name is not resolving to the one i had given it:

```
 class ExecVersionView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name= 'APP/exec.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.versionA = request.GET.get('versionA','')
        self.versionB = request.GET.get('versionB','')
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        versionBint = Version(self.versionB)
        versionAint = Version(self.versionA)
        context = super(ExecVersionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        open_low = ExecVersion.objects.filter(version__gte= versionAint, version__lte=versionBint, severity = 'Low', status='Open')
        context['open_low'] = open_low
        return context
```

Now for some reason this view will give me the wrong template file, And this is doing it to both of those `**` routes/views

I am 100% certain that this is the correct .html file location

Comment: Do you know which template it is rendering? What is the templates structure? Are you trying to override templates here?

Comment: ok EpicView has `template_name="APP/epic.html"` now both of the `**` paths will give me that template when routed to their pages(`index/exec_report`, `index/exec_version_report`)  the templates sit in  `myproject/templates/APP` Now the thing that is wrong is for some reason only these 2 views ignore `template_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"index/exec_report"` matches the path `"index/<slug:key>"` and Django returns the first path that matches. So it returns the detail view with key="exec_report".

Just move your detail path with the slug to a position after the two paths that don't work.

Comment: Ahh i see, it was working earlier with that layout..weird...... That was the problem thanks